# How do I use threading in this situation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

How can i make a small program that prints something endlessly, but I can still use the standard input to write and display something whenever I want?
I found this example, but it terminates after just 2 inputs (and I want to input something multiple times, not just 2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::thread;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int stopflag = 0;

void input_func()
{
    while (true && !stopflag)
    {
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        cout << "Input: " << input << endl;
    }
}

void output_func()
{
    while (true && !stopflag)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        cout << "Output thread\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        thread inp(input_func);
        thread outp(output_func);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

        stopflag = 1;
        outp.join();
        cout << "Joined output thread\n";
        inp.join();
    }
    cout << "End of main, all threads joined.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what the program does? To me, it's not surprising that it terminates. That said, it's not a good example, because it uses an `int` to represent a flag and it accesses that object without synchronization.

Comment: Sorry, but i`m new to multithreading and I don`t really understand it yet. I'll try researching a lot more before asking another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the line `stopflag = 1`. But also, if you want to print the lines you need to add synchronization to modify flag and also printing. Because only one thread should write to console and one time. Don't forget to add flush, as it will not print all text always.